# Over flow hidden and border radius not working when i use css transition scale effects in chrome browser

Tags: html, css

In my demo link, kindly hover the image section, see the image exceed issue.

Over flow hidden and border radius not working when i use css transition scale effects in chrome browser.

It's working fine on Mozilla Firefox, but chrome is not working correctly, i give overflow hidden & border radius but the hover image is exceed on image area.

How to solve this problem. I tried lot's of time, but i can't fix & can't find the correct solution.

**kindly click the demo**

http://tcxsandbox.com/stack-overflow/

And also **check the 2nd comment**, I have placed the fiddle link.

Comment: please include the relevant code here, not on an external site, or create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @serakfalcon. Created a fiddle now. Kindly check it. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhaivendan/htmFL/)

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the parent element in relative position and child with absolute , after use  z-index  and declare parent (with border-radius and overflow hidden) before child . example:

```
     <div class="parent">
         <img  class="child" src="yourimage.jpg" />
     </div>

<style>
      .parent{
         /*must declare border radius and z-index*/
         position: relative;
         border-radius:100px;
         z-index:5;
       }
     .parent img{    /*Child element*/
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out ;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1,1) ;
            -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
            transform: scale(1,1);
            z-index:4;  /*here's where magic happens*/
        }
        .parent img:hover{
            img{
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1) ;
                -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
                -o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
                -ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
            }
        }
</style>
```

this should work.
**NOTE:** i recommend declare border radius for both elements (parent and child ) for prevent crossbrowsing problems .

Answer (score 1):

consider below code:

```
.box-main-img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-radius` to your box-main-img class

```
.box-main-img {
float: left;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
height: 143px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/htmFL/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Danield, border radius is working fine on normal, but when hover the image the transition effects exceed in image area at that time is not working, please could you see your fiddle once again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: Could you please see the 4 corners in my screenshot. This is appeared on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.102. When hover the image area, border radius and overflow hidden not working. Kindly check the screen shot http://tcxsandbox.com/stack-overflow/screenshot.jpg

Comment: I'm using chrome 33 and I don't see the black corners like in the screen shot.

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time with me, If you have any ideas, kindly let me know